# displaying store specific products magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hi I am using Magento CE.

I am looking display store specific products.

When I am adding a product and under websites tab I can see the store I have created, but unable set that option.

Is there any restriction in CE?

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a different products for each store for example en products, pl products etc. You have to create a root category for each store and when you create this store you have to choose particular root category. So for example when you are creating English shop you have to select root category with English products.

Hope this will help. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For each store we need to create root category, then the same mapped to the products under the store.

Example :

Store_A,
Store_B and 
Store_C

Root_Cat_A,
Root_Cat_B and
Root_Cat_C

**store   | website  |root_category| sku**  
Store_A | Website  | Root_Cat_A | SKU01 
Store_A | Website  | Root_Cat_A | SKU02 
Store_A | Website  | Root_Cat_A | SKU03 
Store_B | Website  | Root_Cat_B | SKU04 
Store_B | Website  | Root_Cat_B | SKU05 
Store_B | Website  | Root_Cat_B | SKU06 
Store_C | Website  | Root_Cat_C | SKU07 
Store_C | Website  | Root_Cat_C | SKU08 
Store_C | Website  | Root_Cat_C | SKU09

Thanks.